# Automating the printing of multiple .DWG files in Autocad

Tags: vb.net, autocad

I have a VB.NET project in which it would be extremely helpful to the users if they would be able to print multiple .DWG files at the same time without manually opening each one and clicking on the print button.

Is this possible to do in VB.NET using the Autocad API's?

Comment: http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2011/ENU/filesMDG/WS1a9193826455f5ff2566ffd511ff6f8c7ca-4875.htm

Comment: This is definitely possible. However, since the user has to open the drawing to print it, would it be simpler to just use the built-in PUBLISH command to achieve the same outcome?

Answer (score 1):

Modern versions of AutoCAD now come with batch printing utilities.  Before that, I programmed a tool that would assemble a list of drawing names into an AutoCAD script file then run it.  That might work for you too.  Printing is only the beginning of what your users can do once you give them the ability for unattended editing of a list of drawings.

I'd be glad to give you pointers.  Here's a sample of such a script file you can build and run:

```
sdi 1 qsave open "P:\21049 SMCFD\21049.34 Barleen\dwg\4934sh01.dwg"
filedia 0 cmddia 0
my_cool_plot_command_etc
filedia 1 cmddia 1
qsave open "P:\21049 SMCFD\21049.34 Barleen\dwg\4934sh02.dwg"
filedia 0 cmddia 0
my_cool_plot_command_etc
filedia 1 cmddia 1
qsave open "P:\21049 SMCFD\21049.34 Barleen\dwg\4934sh03.dwg"
filedia 0 cmddia 0
my_cool_plot_command_etc
filedia 1 cmddia 1
qsave open "P:\21049 SMCFD\21049.34 Barleen\dwg\4934sh04.dwg"
filedia 0 cmddia 0
my_cool_plot_command_etc
filedia 1 cmddia 1
qsave sdi 0
```